# Infopath - Create a drop-down List from Active Directory "Department" field

Tags: infopath2010

Is it possible to create a Drop-down list in InfoPath which connects to Active Directory and fills the list with UNIQUE Department Values only (no repeating ones)

I need this for an InfoPath so when a user entering the data can pick one of the departments listed in the drop-down. Any help would be appreciated.

I've had a look at the people picker control, which works great for User names, but the department field is a separate field and has nothing to do with the user I pick, so I simply need a control which is populated by the unique Department codes in AD.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should really contact your administrator for this sort of information.  You do not want a form to query every AD user to pull their department and get the unique values just to populate a drop down list.  It is very possible to obtain the list of unique directories, however you should work with your administrator to populate this data to an XML web page or other similar solution and then connect your form to THAT data source through the form.  The point is you are missing a step of obtaining the queried data.

With that said you can obtain the department of the user by querying the get user profile service to obtain the department name, elinating the need to even create a populated drop down list. See this [article.](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx#13692)